# Magento Fortis Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I am using Fortis theme in Magento. I trying to add jQuery code in it. I am using below location to add jQuery.

```
skin/frontend/base/default/js/app.js
```

Here is my code to add jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    jQuery("#my_form").submit(function()
    {
        alert('Yes');
    });
});
```

But my code is not working. Can anyone say where is the problem??

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Below code is working

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        jQuery(".form_label").click(function()
        {
            alert('Yes');
        });
    });
```

It seems strange to me.If I put a click event on form label then it is working but if I put submit event on the form then it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure about this theme that you are using, but maybe try to include this within a form. Check if this code is actually loading within your DOM. Please also provide the button itself.

Answer (score 0):

add your js file  from head.phtml  and than  view source your page  that  your included file is loaded or not .  and before doing this  you can   test  your code by running it in  console in inspect element.